# Subclassed button not producing animation on every repeated click

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi, button, subclass

I have a custom subclassed button created in the `WM_CREATE` message of my `WindowProc` callback. Here are the creation and subclassing instructions, along with a structure used to control the button state:

```
static button_state btnstateBtnInstall;
hBtnInstall = CreateWindow(WC_BUTTON, L"Button", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, (window_width / 2) - (btn_install_width / 2), window_height - (window_height / 6) - (btn_install_height / 2), btn_install_width, btn_install_height, hwnd, (HMENU)HMENU_btn_install, NULL, NULL);
SetWindowSubclass(hBtnInstall, BtnInstallProc, 0, (DWORD_PTR)&btnstateBtnInstall);
```

The struct is defined as follows:

```
struct button_state
{
    bool pushed;
    button_state() { pushed = false; }
};
```

The subclassed procedure is coded as follows:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK BtnInstallProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubClass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    button_state* state = (button_state*)dwRefData;

    // Omitted part where I create brushes and font to be used for painting

    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        RECT rc = ps.rcPaint;

        POINT pt;
        GetCursorPos(&pt);
        ScreenToClient(hwnd, &pt);
        BOOL hover = PtInRect(&rc, pt);

        if (state->pushed)
        {
            // Pushed
            FillRect(hdc, &rc, hBrPushed);
        }
        else if (hover)
        {
            // Mouse over
            FillRect(hdc, &rc, hBrHover);
        }
        else
        {
            // Normal
            FillRect(hdc, &rc, hBrNormal);
        }

        SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);
        SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(255, 255, 255));
        SelectFont(hdc, SegoeUI);
        static LPCWSTR InstallBtnTxt = L"Install";
        static int InstallBtnTxtLen = static_cast<int>(wcslen(InstallBtnTxt));  // Should be a safe cast, for small arrays like this one
        DrawText(hdc, InstallBtnTxt, InstallBtnTxtLen, &rc, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        return 0;
    }

    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    {
        state->pushed = true;

        break;
    }

    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
    {
        state->pushed = false;

        break;
    }

    // Omitted part where I handle WM_DESTROY to do cleanup

    }

    return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

To compare the behaviour of my button with a standard one, I created another button without subclassing and using only the standard `BUTTON` class and `WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD` attributes.

As you can see from the attached gif, when I **repeatedly click on a standard class button, every click produces the animation** while when hitting multiple times **the button I created** with this code it seems like it **isn't catching every click but (as you can see) something like 50% of them**.

What am I missing? Why isn't my button as responsive as the one that comes with the standard class?

**TL;DR**: when clicking slowly on my subclassed button, the painting is correct. As you can see from my attached image, the difference between mine and a standard button is big when repeating clicks on them. How can I make my control be as responsive as the standard one?

[image]

Comment: Rather than painting the hard way, the fast button may have a cached bitmap it can draw lightning fast. Also, are you testing a debug or optimized build? Don't waste your time speed testing optimized builds. The library button call is going to be optimized to the gills and if yours isn't, there's likely no fair comparison.

Comment: Why are you custom-drawing a button without giving it the `BS_OWNERDRAW` style?

Comment: Since button like this one will be of various sizes and with various texts sharing this subclassed procedure, I can not use bitmaps. Owner-draw and Custom-draw are not possibilities as well, here. The image you see is taken from a debug scenario. You mean I should test the release one? I tried but unfortunately the "lag" is still there

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am subclassing it entirely. I am not using Owner-drawing or Custom-drawing as they are mostly affected by Windows themes. Should I still be using `BS_OWNERDRAW` when subclassing?

Comment: My apologies for being unclear. I'm not talking a bitmap file. Draw once and cache. If the object is resized or otherwise altered you draw again and cache; otherwise, display the cache.

Comment: @user4581301 no problem and thanks a lot for helping! So you mean I should store a bitmap in memory representing the whole button (with background and text) for each state and then only "paste" the correct one from memory when the button state changes? If I am correct, could you provide some function names I could use? I could not find references, Googling

Comment: To be honest, I don't know win32 graphics. That's just a description of the sort of thing the sort of thing I used to do in Java swing and playing dirty rectangle on displays for embedded systems.

Comment: Since you don't use owner-draw or custom draw, the system still tries to render animations, which interfers with your own drawing code. Tell the system that you don't want that by using custom draw (the prefered method because you can keep all window style flags). Custom draw is *not* affected by theming, when you draw everything by yourself.

Comment: Handle [NM_CUSTOMDRAW (button)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/nm-customdraw-button) instead of `WM_PAINT`. Don't set `BS_OWNERDRAW`, which isn't needed when using *custom draw*.

Comment: @zett42 I tried and now this problem is solved but I still get the animation that makes transition from one color to another when the button state changes. I would like to have no fading at all but just the change of background color. How can I achieve that?

Comment: *I tried and now this problem is solved but....* what did you actually do to solve it? Did you use ` NM_CUSTOMDRAW` correctly to draw your button?

Comment: @user4581301: *"The hard way"*, as you describe it, *is* lightning fast. It's a `FillRect` followed by `DrawText`. This may well be faster than blitting an offscreen bitmap.

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε yes, I used `NM_CUSTOMDRAW` in `WM_NOTIFY`. Anyway, the issue was related to WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK that was not handled. See accepted answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are clicking fast some `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` messages are substituted by the `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` (default double click handling). You need to handle it just like you are handling the `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` message.

```
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
case WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK: // <-- Added
{
    state->pushed = true;

    break;
}
```

Comment: You made my day! That solved the issue without using the `NM_CUSTOMDRAW`